# Trigger on AccountTag object

Tags: trigger, tag

Using Eclipse/Dev Console, is it possible to put a trigger on the AccountTag object?  What I want to do is to copy the tags, as they are added, to a reportable field so that reports can be run with filters on tags.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible :(, get an error message saying the sObject type is not supported for triggers

Comment: Hi, I answered my own question, replying that it is not possible.  I'm note sure how that does not answer the question.